# 3d arcgis raster .tiff image to CFD software

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d, autocad, stl

I am trying to export 3d raster image prepared in ArcGIS to cfd package such as Fluent. I was wondering if anyone has experience to convert raster image to autocad 3d format, stl, vrml or any other format of its likes which could be imported to cfd package.

I could import format likes IGES, .stl, .DWG, .DXF or even text files.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and use the [STL](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tags/stl/) plugin to save the data. As simple as opening the raster and then "Save As"